# How to pack a .NET 6 WPF app using Windows Application Packaging Project with Framework-Dependent?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-6.0, windows-store, windows-application-packaging

I have a WPF app `App1` (.NET 6 with `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>`) and my client would like to distribute it through MS Store so I created a [`Windows Application Packaging Project`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) and add reference back to `App1`. Everything works well and we can publish our app except with just a Hello World project, the package size is more than **60MB** (for neutral arch).

I understand it is due to it packing the whole .NET 6 with it. Is there a way to publish it using framework-dependent model instead? We don't mind user being asked to download and install it if they don't have it already installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to create a framework-dependent MSIX package:

- Right click on the WPF project (not the Windows Application Packaging Project) in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and choose Publish
- Choose **Folder** as both target and specific target and accept the default location in the wizard
- Click on the "Show all settings" link of the created publish profile and set the target runtime to **win-x86** or **win-x64** depending on your CPU architecture requirements
- Make sure that the deployment mode is set to **Framework-dependent**
- Click Save
- Go to the Windows Application Packaging Project, expand the Dependencies->Applications node, select the referenced WPF application project and set its Publishing Profile property to the `Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml` file that you created in the previous wizard
- Re-publish the Windows Application Packaging Project with the same CPU architecture and configuration you have configured the publishing profile for

Comment: I am also interested in this matter and created fresh WPF and Packaging projects in Visual Studio 17.2.5 (in win-x86 or win-x64) following your instruction as much as possible. But still the size of final appxupload file is over 60 MB. There might be something I missed.

Comment: The you did something wrong. Did you really select the same CPU architecture and configuration in the publish wizard and the selected publishing profile?

Comment: Such as for example `Neutral `/ `Debug (Any CPU)`?

Comment: I have the same result as @emoacht. The final output size (..msixbundle) is still 62MB. I even tried publishing the WPF app manually and the size was ~150KB so the Publish Profile was correct. The arch should match because I cannot create app package if it doesn't match. Also using the latest VS 17.2.5.

Comment: @mm8 Thanks. I haven't changed platform in both solution's properties and project's properties from default (Any CPU) to x86. After setting them to x86, and specifying win-x86, the size of appxupload file became less than 100 KB.

Comment: It's so strange I don't know what I did wrong before, but now it works for me, upload size is 84KB. I noticed the `Publishing Profile` value wasn't showing and I had to pick it again. It's weird but I can confirm it works :)

Comment: Just a follow up question: is it possible to use Neutral arch instead of specifying x64/x86 only? I tried `Portable` for WPF project but it wouldn't work as it show as "MSIL" for arch.

Comment: Publishing the WAP project with a neutral archiecture works for me. The target runtime of the publish profile of the WPF project still needs to be set to win-x*.